# Update state in object inside other object, React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spread

well, i have an object inside another object, and i want to update the state in one property or more in the second object, this is the state :

```js
const [products, setProducts] = useState({
  name: '',
  type: '',
  price: '',
  sizes: { s: false, m: false, l: false, xl: false }
});
```

how can i access a property in the second object i've tried this but it's not working :

```js
setProducts({...products, sizes : {...sizes, sizes[m] : true}}) // this not working
```

is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```js
setProducts({ ...products, sizes: { ...products.sizes, m: true } });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
setProducts(prevState=> ({ ...prevState, sizes: { ...prevState.sizes, m: true } }));
```

this will also prevent issues in case of closure

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update additional sizes with either `true` or `false` you could abstract that into

```
const updateSize = (field, value) => {
  setProducts(prevState=> ({ 
    ...prevState,
    sizes: { ...prevState.sizes, [field]: value }
  }));
}
```